# Adding in C# asp.net when the Dropdown is populated by the client using JSON

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, c#-4.0, json.net

I heres my code in Json

```
function OnGetNotes(index) {
        proxyNotes.invoke("SearchBranchesByBankID",{ "request":{"BankID": index}
                            }, OnGetNotesComplete, OnError);
    }
    function OnGetNotesComplete(result) {
        var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(result);
        var notes = obj.Branches;
        if (notes.length > 0) {
            for (var i = 0; i < notes.length; i++) {
                var item = notes[i]; 
                $("#<%=cboBranch.ClientID%>").append($("<option></option>").val(notes[i].ID).html(notes[i].BranchName));                                    
            }
```

Heres the code in my c# WHICH IN I CANNOT ACCESS THE SELECTED VALUE OF THE DROPDOWN OF THE BRANCH when i press the add button

```
protected void btnSaveBank_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (int.Parse(cboBank.SelectedValue) != -1)
        {
            int bankID = int.Parse(cboBank.SelectedValue);
            string bankName = cboBank.SelectedItem.Text;
            int branchID = int.Parse(cboBranch.SelectedValue);//this have no value at all
            string branchName = cboBranch.SelectedItem.Text;//and also this
            string accName = txtAccountName.Text;
            string accNo = txtAccountNumber.Text;
            DateTime tdate = UtilityHelper.ConvertToDateTime(txtToDateBank.Text);
            DateTime fdate = UtilityHelper.ConvertToDateTime(txtFromDateBank.Text);

            AddContractorBankAccountDetails(bankID, bankName, 1, "branch one", accName, accNo, tdate, fdate);
        }
        else
        {
            alertBoxBank.Visible = true;
        }
    }
```

Thanks You

Answer (score 0):

```
 int bankID = int.Parse(cboBank.SelectedValue.toString());
```

use toString at last....or you can also do this by

int bankID = int.Parse(cboBank.SelectedItem.toString());

this will depend upon your item value..

Comment: I think my syntax is correct but my problem here is that when I select a bank in bankDDL, I populate data using the Json and jQuery. And the main problem is that when I click the button add I cannot get the cbo.Branch selected index, instead it is null

Comment: yeah...syntax is right but i think at wrong place... have you tried out selecteditem.tostring() ...?

Comment: Yes, but it didnt work. the bank is working the main problem is the branches

Comment: if it is showing value as  null...then it simply means that it is only showing you item...it is not at all taking value of that item...check that  string branchName = cboBranch.Text; is working or not??

Comment: nope. :(, I have a question it doesnt matter at all I populate the ddl using Jquery not in c#? I think I cannot access the date bacause I dont use datasource and databind.